# apache ignite - ssd persistence writing issue

Tags: java, datagrid, ignite

I'm facing an issue when enable *persistence* to use *SSD*, detail as flowing:

`dataRegionConfiguration.setPersistenceEnabled(true)`, and set durable memory max size as **40G**, write data through `datastreamer.adddata` method, everything works fine, but after some time, when the data in durable memory reaches **40*0.9=36G**, apache ignite start page eviction,  after the page eviction, writing data become slower and slower.

> e.g. from 60m/s to 30m/s, 20m/s, 15m/s and so on.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: after the page eviction, I find that the ssd reading speed is growing, while the ssd writing speed is dropping. I don't know why the reading happens, I'm only writing data until now.

Comment: apache ignite version is 2.3

Comment: You may be affected by the IGNITE-7638 issue. It is in PATCH_AVAILABLE, so you can monitor the fix and build Ignite from sources to check the fix once the issue is merged to master.

Answer (score 1):

Try to tune the durable memory as well as the persistence first as suggested [here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/durable-memory-tuning). For instance, you should try to:

- Store WAL and persistence data files on separate drives.
- Enable pages writes throttling.
- Reconfigure checkpointing buffer size.

Comment: these above mentioned are all checked and done, doesn't work. I have been testing for one month

Answer (score 0):

after the page eviction, I find that the ssd reading speed is growing, while the ssd writing speed is dropping. I don't know why the reading happens, I'm only writing data until now.

Comment: I do remember community was fighting the issues like that and merged special optimizations in Ignite 2.4. The release will be announced the next week. Give it a try and let me know the results.

Comment: Ignite master branch has fixed the dropping performance issue. If you rebuild from the master, you should have a significantly improved behavior.

Comment: Reading is needed because data is written to partially full data pages. They have to be updated so theyb have to be read first.

Comment: I'm testing this issue on 2.5.0 snapshot with one client node and three server nodes, writing data from client node through streamer.loaddata, find that the data is only written to ssd on one server node, why?

Comment: @Will First, it is not recommended to use snapshot releases. Try sticking to official releases, the latest of which is Ignite 2.4. Second, it seems that it's a different issue. Please create another question and make sure that you describe it in detail so that the community can help you.